# Want to show real estate data in my website. need suggestions

Tags: api

i am looking to make a real estate page in my site where i want to show list of house for sale in particular location. I would like to use api for this. If you people has suggestions let me know. Your suggestions are really important :)

website i will be use is: http://citystir.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried it, but here is one:
http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm

Answer (score -1):

Better way use RETS IDX MLS feed for listing from realtor Service Provider and make MLS Feed System for Daily Property Update May Be used [RETSIQ](http://www.retsiq.com/) or [PHRETS](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS)

if Any More detail skype :shailesh.makwana990

Comment: Do not contact this guys. He will ask you money.

Comment: I am asking for service , No Buddy work in free without wasting time